# Trying to match an a date with a value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to find a way to do the follow:

When I input a date example `1/1/17` in Cell `A1` on 'Tab 2', I would like cell A2 to match a number value that corresponds with the matching date in 'Tab 1'

Example

I input `1/1/17` in cell `A1` in 'Tab 2'

(in tab 1)

```
cell H7 = 1/1/17
cell I7 = 100
```

I'd like to figure out how to make a formula where cell `A2` on 'tab 2'
will automatically put the value from column I that matches the date in column H.

Does that make sense?

So if I put `1/1/17` in `A1` 'Tab2'

`100` would automatically show up in `A2` 'Tab2'

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

I cell `A2` You should use the [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) function.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!H7:I7,2)
```

In this example the lookup table is only one row deep, but hopefully this illustrates what you are after.